# VB Script simple loop question

Tags: loops, vbscript

I have have a simple script that I do not wish to close (exit) at the end. I would like it to start at the beginning again.

```
Dim FJobName, objShell, FRevent, FReventNo, FPrevJobName
FJobName=InputBox ("Job Name","Plates Complete","ACT")
result=Msgbox(FJobName ,vbYesNo, "New Job?")
If result = vbYes Then
FRevent="raiseevent SetJobStatus_r3 " & FJobName & " InCart New -host 194.128.255.22 -port 61235"
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run FRevent
Else
If result = vbNo Then
result=Msgbox(FJobName ,vbYesNo, "Repeat Job?")
If result = vbYes Then
FPrevJobName=InputBox ("Previous Job Name?","Plates Complete","")
result=Msgbox(FPrevJobName ,vbYesNo, "Is this correct?")
If result = vbYes Then
FReventNo="raiseevent SetJobStatus_r3 " & FJobName & " InCart Repeat  " & FPrevJobName & " -host 194.128.255.22 -port 61235"
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run FReventNo
End If
End If
End If
End If
```

Comment: I have formatted your code as code, next time choose to do this yourself, the button can be found on the edit window menu bar and look like this: `{}` To ensure a prompt answer, you might like to take the time to indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in a while loop.  You can set ending criteria or prompt the user.  Something along these lines:

```
While 1=1
    ' *Your Code Here*

    ' Prompt user to quit/continue
    If msgbox("Continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        WScript.quit
    End If
    ' Alternately check criteria to quit/continue
    if myQuitCriteria = True Then
        WScript.quit
    End If
Wend
```